# Scala Slick 3.1 multiple joins

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to perform multiple joins in Slick 3.1.1. The result that I would like to achieve is this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN customer_address ON customer.id = customer_address.customer_id LEFT JOIN address ON customer_address.address_id = address.id
```

I have tried the following:

```
val query = for {
  c <- Customer
  ca <- CustomerAddress if ca.customerId === c.id
  a <- Address if a.id === ca.addressId
} yield (c, a)
```

The problem here is that if a customer doesn't have an address that it doesn't appear which makes sense.

Then I tried this:

```
    val query2 = for {
       (c, ca, a) <- (Customer joinLeft CustomerAddress on (_.id === _.customerId)) joinLeft Address on (_._2.addressId === _.id)
    } yield (c, a)
```

The problem here is that I get an error on `_._2.addressId` because `_._2` is a `Rep` object.

Exact error:

```
Error:(21, 110) value addressId is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Models.Tables.CustomerAddress]]
  (c, ca, a) <- (Customer joinLeft CustomerAddress on (_.id === _.customerId)) joinLeft Address on (_._2.addressId === _.id)
```

Auto generated Slick Tables class:
http://pastebin.com/e4M3cGU8

How can I get the results that I want with Slick?

Comment: Can you please add the error you receive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have to do is also map the results.

```
val query2 = for {
      ((c, ca), a) <- (Customer joinLeft CustomerAddress on (_.id === _.customerId)) joinLeft Address on (_._2.map(_.addressId) === _.id)
} yield (c, a)
```

Comment: this is the right answer but this syntax is nauseating. i thought slick would solve problems for me but i've just been met with frustrations like this

Comment: Is there any cleaner way introduced in slick to do this yet? This is quite common use-case (at least for us) and this makes code really ugly!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is also like other answers, But more clear and more readable.

```
val query2 = for {
    ((customer, customerAddress), address) <-
        (Customer joinLeft CustomerAddress on
            {
                case(customerTable,customerAddressTable) =>
                    (customerTable.id === customerAddressTable.customerId)
            }
        ) joinLeft Address on
            {
                case ((customerTable,customerAddressTable),addressTable) =>
                    (customerAddressTable.map(_.addressId) === addressTable.id)
            }
} yield (customer, address)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work. // `((c, ca), a)` instead of `(c, ca, a)`

```
val query2 = for {
   ((c, ca), a) <- (Customer joinLeft CustomerAddress on (_.id === _.customerId)) joinLeft Address on (_._2.addressId === _.id)
} yield (c, a)
```

Comment: @JellevanEs Looks like the configuration for `Table` is wrong. Would it be possible to share `Customer`, `CustomerAddress` and `Address` definition? Look like you have missed using `Option` in one of those table definition?

Comment: I added the Table class. I don't know if you can do something with it because it is auto generated by slick